# Defining multiple, similar macros

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining multiple shorthands quickly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30349/defining-multiple-shorthands-quickly)

I am using

```
\def\Ac{\mathcal{A}}
```

However, I want similar macros like `\Bc`, `\Cc`, ... `\Zc`. Instead of defining them all manually, is there a simpler way to define all?

---

SOLUTION FOUND:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{\@namedef{#1c}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}}}
\docsvlist{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Defining multiple shorthands quickly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30349/defining-multiple-shorthands-quickly) and tell us if the answer there helped. We would close this question as a duplicate then.