# Defining an anaphoric macro to define multiple commands based on a template

Tags: macros, expansion

I am in the process of writing commands to typeset chord tabulatures for guitar using TikZ. Because for every chord, there are two equivalent (enharmonic) names, I want to avoid redundancy when defining them, so I want to write a macro which produces slightly different code for every one of them. However, contrary to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30349/defining-multiple-shorthands-quickly), since the typeset chord name needs to be included in the TikZ code, I need to handle an additional argument which can vary for each version of the command name.

Since I use TikZ anyway, my approach was to use a two-variable `\foreach` loop and a kind of [anaphoric macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) `\newchord` (BTW, I find it interesting that this term is apparently not common for TeX), which uses a `\chordname` command that should be expanded to the respective name in each definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\newchord}[2]{%
  \foreach \command / \name in {#1} {%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname \command\endcsname{%
      \def\chordname{\name}
      #2
    }
  }
}

% this is how I want to use the macro:
\newchord{ASharp/{A\(\sharp\)}, BFlat/{B\(\flat\)}}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}

\begin{document}
\ASharp % -> I am: A♯
\BFlat % -> I am: B♭
\end{document}
```

This example fails with

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> \chordname ->\name
>
> l.20 \ASharp

I suspect that is because `\chordname` is expanded too early, but honestly, I don't really know much about expansion, anyway...

I wouldn't mind a solution not using `\foreach`, this was just what I found the easiest to start with. Also the way of using `\chordname` was just an idea -- as long as a solution works similar to my usage example, it's OK (but it would be interesting to get it work). The slash as separator is also not significant, it is just what `\foreach` requires to work.

Comment: I think, this is easier with `expl3` features

Comment: @christian I'd be OK with that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual problem: you have to expand `\command` and `\name`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\newchord}[2]{%
  \foreach \command/\name in {#1} {%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname \command\endcsname{%
      \def\noexpand\chordname{\unexpanded\expandafter{\name}}%
      \unexpanded{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}

% this is how I want to use the macro:
\newchord{ASharp/{A\(\sharp\)}, BFlat/{B\(\flat\)}}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}

\begin{document}
\ASharp % -> I am: A♯

\BFlat % -> I am: B♭
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newchord}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \phg_newchord:nn { ##1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \phg_newchord:nn
 {
  \__phg_newchord:nw {#2} #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__phg_newchord:nw #1 #2/#3 \q_stop
 {
  \cs_new:cpn { #2 }
   {
    \cs_set:Npn \chordname { #3 }
    #1
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% this is how I want to use the macro:
\newchord{
  ASharp/A\(\sharp\),
  BFlat/B\(\flat\)
}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}

\begin{document}
\ASharp % -> I am: A♯

\BFlat % -> I am: B♭
\end{document}
```

A second version with a slightly different syntax (but better, in my opinion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newchord}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \phg_newchord:nn { ##1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__phg_newchord_replacement_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \phg_newchord:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__phg_newchord_replacement_tl { #2 }
  \keys_set:nn { phg/newchord } { #1 }
 }
\keys_define:nn { phg/newchord}
 {
  unknown .code:n = \__phg_newchord_define:Vn \l_keys_key_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__phg_newchord_define:nn
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpx { #1 }
   {
    \cs_set:Npn \exp_not:N \chordname { \exp_not:n { #2 } }
    \exp_not:V \l__phg_newchord_replacement_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__phg_newchord_define:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% this is how I want to use the macro:
\newchord{
  ASharp = A\(\sharp\),
  BFlat = B\(\flat\),
}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}

\begin{document}
\ASharp % -> I am: A♯

\BFlat % -> I am: B♭
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. I have tried `xdef` alone before, but could explain a bit why the the "unexpansions" help to make it work in the correct order? Just for me learning to prevent usual mistakes in the future...

Comment: @phg `\xdef` is needed because you want the definition to be global; you just have to not go all the way down, so `\unexpanded\expandafter{\name}` just does one step of expansion, leaving the meaning of `\name`; the `#2` part should not be expanded at all, so it's passed through `\unexpanded`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. While I agree that the third version has the better syntax, I think I will still use the first one, since it's the only one I can really read ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pgfkeys` and its `.list` handler to avoid global definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
  chords/.is family,chords,
  define/.code args={#1/#2/#3}{
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{%
      \def\chordname{#2}
      #3
    }
  },
}
\newcommand{\newchord}[2]{%
  \pgfkeys{chords,
    define hardcode/.style={define=##1/#2},
    define hardcode/.list={#1},
  }
}

% this is how I want to use the macro:
\newchord{ASharp/{A\(\sharp\)}, BFlat/{B\(\flat\)}}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}

\begin{document}
\ASharp % -> I am: A♯
\BFlat % -> I am: B♭
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A version with `expl3` and direct expansion on definition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \newchord #1 {%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {/} {##1} 
    \cs_gset:cpx {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newchord{ASharp/{A\(\sharp\)}, BFlat/{B\(\flat\)}}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  %I am: \chordname
}

\begin{document}
\ASharp % -> I am: A♯

\BFlat % -> I am: B♭
\end{document}
```

Comment: And where would I put in a template here? If the "I am:" line is uncommented, this leads to an error. Modifying the code to use `{I am \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}` also does not gain much, as that would then be constant for all definitions, wouldn't it?

Comment: Because `\chordname` is not  defined, of course. It's an error to use it the preamble anyway then -- and  your initial example does use it the preamble...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the `listofitems` package to parse the data.

EDITED to give the syntax specified by the OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newtoks\Chordtoks
\newtoks\ChordDatatoks
\newcommand{\addtotoks}[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\newcommand{\xaddtotoks}[2]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}
\newcommand\newchord[2]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist*\ChordList{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\ChordList{%
    \setsepchar[$]{/}%
    \readlist*\ChordData{\x}%
    \ChordDatatoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ChordData[2]}%
    \Chordtoks{\def\chordname}%
    \xaddtotoks\Chordtoks{\the\ChordDatatoks}%
    \addtotoks\Chordtoks{#2}%
    \def\tmp{\expandafter\def\csname\ChordData[1]\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\Chordtoks}%
  }%
}
\newchord{ASharp/{A\(\sharp\)}, BFlat/{B\(\flat\)}}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}
\begin{document}
\ASharp

\BFlat
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\newchord[2]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist*\ChordList{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\ChordList{%
    \setsepchar[$]{/}%
    \readlist*\ChordData{\x}%
    \def\tmp{\expandafter\def\csname\ChordData[1]\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ChordData[2]}%
    \def\chordname{\csname\ChordData[1]\endcsname}%
    #2\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\newchord{ASharp/{A\(\sharp\)}, BFlat/{B\(\flat\)}}{%
  % here, actually some TikZ drawing will happen
  I am: \chordname
}
\end{document}
```

I have separately verified that `\ASharp` contains the tokens `{A\(\sharp\)}` and likewise, `\BFlat` contains the tokens `{B\(\flat\)}` [for this original approach].